# Parse string character by character in shell script

Tags: shell, string-parsing

I am trying to parse a url to extract some text from it so that i can use the same to rename my file when i download it. Basically i want to write to a shell script to do this. I would like to collect the url into a string and then parse it character by character. How could this be done in shell script???

Comment: Your download tool doesn't support `Content-Disposition`?

Comment: i am feeding a set of links to my download program which would download it with some random sequence of chars which i would like to rename it with that present in the url

Comment: You should really say how the URL looks, how you get it and what you want to extract from it.

Comment: my url will be like this: youtube.com/watch?v=Od3xkrxcsE8&feature=relmfu and of which i would like to extract Od3xkrxcsE8

Comment: @nikhil: Do **not comment**, edit the question!

Answer (score 1):

You can read a string char-by-char by using the `Substring Expansion` syntax:

```
${parameter:offset:length}
```

Example:

```
str="abcd"
char=${str:1:1} # => "b"
```

And get the length of the string with the `Parameter length` syntax:

```
${#parameter}
```

Example:

```
${#str}
```

So you can iterate over the characters by using this:

```
for (( i = 0; i < ${#str}; ++i)); do
    echo "${str:$i:1}"
done
```

From the bash manual:

> `${#parameter}`
>
> `Parameter length`.  The length in  characters  of  the  value  of              `parameter`  is  substituted.

> `${parameter:offset}`
>   `${parameter:offset:length}`
>
> `Substring Expansion`.  Expands to  up  to  length  characters  of `parameter`  starting  at  the  character specified by `offset`.

Comment: -1: [Shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) does not have anything like substring expansion!

Comment: It does work in bash. But that's far from synonym to shell these days. For interactive use, there are much more capable shells (ok, it works in zsh too, but than there are much better ways there) and for scripting use, there much faster shells. Where this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the filename to save to:

```
url="http://www.example.com/path?foo#bar"
echo $(basename "${url%%[?#]*}")
# => "path"
```

How it works:

- `"${url%%[?#]*}"` removes any thing after `?` and `#` (it removes the query and the hash)
- `$(basename "...")` returns the last path component (the part after the last /)

Comment: Depends. Should the file be saved as 'path' or 'foo'?

Comment: what is that basename??? and my url will be like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Od3xkrxcsE8&feature=relmfu and of which i would like to extract Od3xkrxcsE8

Comment: Browsers would default to `path` (and ignore the query)

Comment: would like to extract content present in between ? and & without v=..simply stating i need only Od3xkrxcsE if my input url is the above one

Answer (score 0):

```
url='http://youtube.com/watch?v=Od3xkrxcsE8&feature=relmfu'
url=${url#*v=}
url=${url%%&*}
```

or you can use sed, which is less efficient (starts external command), but more flexible and for more complicated cases also more readable.

```
url='http://youtube.com/watch?v=Od3xkrxcsE8&feature=relmfu'
url=$(printf '%s' "$url" | sed 's+.*v=\([^&]*\).*+\1+')
```

Note, that in *shell* (`/bin/sh`), the `${var#prefix-pattern}` and `${var%suffix-pattern}` are the *only* string manipulation functions available. In *bash* or *zsh* you have many more, but always be aware that you are using such extension, because some systems have simpler shell installed as `/bin/sh` and some (usually other Unix flavours than Linux or embedded systems) systems don't have bash at all.

Comment: -1: You didn't escaped your assignment. It executes feature=relmfu in a subshell

Comment: arnaud576875: Right. Fixed quotes.